# Accidentally inserted a string into a big int column. Is there any chance of recovering the string?

Tags: sql, mysql, database

When parsing and inserting data, I accidentally inserted a string (ip address) into a bigint column in a MySQL table without using the `INET_ATON` function. Is there any way I can recover the original string?

Comment: Whats gone is gone and will never come back! To the best of my knowledge- No!! :-( If by chance it is crucial and you are logging it in original form..thats a long shot but possible!!

Comment: @In Sane: :( Its billions of records so I was hoping I could do something... Guess I'm left with no options then... :(

Comment: how about restoring old backups of your data? The last backed up data might go some way towards restoring the values depending on your backup frequency of course!!

Comment: @In Sane: Actually its not about a backup. I started the job a few days back parsing a lot of log files. I still have the log files but its taking about 3 days to insert everything into a database... I was just hoping there is a way to avoid this but looks like I'll have to do this again...

Answer (score 0):

If you insert an ip address like this:

```
INSERT INTO test values("123.456.888.999");
```

then it'll be inserted as 123456, so you still have first 2 digits, but the rest is lost